# If column B has "1" then show contents from Column A

Tags: excel-formula

As the title implies, I'm trying to have column C tell me all of the results of A in which the corresponding B value is a "1" for example.
So if this was my data set:

a   0
b   1
c   0
d   1
e   0
f   1
g   0
Then anytime we see a 1 for example from B1:B6, I want it to show A1:A6
Using    If=(B1=1,A1, ) for each row, I get a result such as this:

a0
b1b

c0
d1d

e0
f1f

g0

However, I'm hoping to avoid the spaces between the rows for the third column as Ultimately I'm putting this on a different tab of the worksheet, meaning I was hoping for it to look like:

a0b

b1d

c0f

d1
e0
f1
g0
Using If=(B1:B6=1,A1=A6, ) I was able to get it to show just a single result of just b, but again that doesn't show me d or f in the neat little column I'm hoping for. I tried to just sort it afterwards based on alphabetical afterwards using the first formula, but this works for about 1/4 second before it unsorts itself.
I apologize if this type of question has been answered before, I didn't see anything, but then again with my relative lack of experience with excel I could have skipped right over it because I'm not familiar with the jargon. Oh and just to clarify, I don't need help putting it on a different tab. That's at least one thing I know how to do. I also hope the columns make sense, the formatting kept changing so I had to change it up a bit, and I can't post pics until 10 reputation. Thanks!

Comment: Please narrow down you question (or split it into separate ones), and show your work highlighting the essential part causing the problem, so we would be able to help you. Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something from your question, the answer to this is fairly simple.

I assume you are starting with this:

[image]

And you would like to get to this:

[image]

If so, the formula in Cell C1 should be:

> =IF(B1=1,A1,"")

You can then use the fill handle to replicate this down as far as you require.

My only other interpretation is that you would like the outcome to be this:

[image]

If so, then the formulae in Cell C1 should be:

> =IF(B1=1,A1 & B1 & A1,"")

Then again use the Fill handle to replicate the formula down as far as required.